# Swift: subscript vs. callAsFunction

Tags: swift

What's the difference between `subscript` and `callAsFunction`? From my point of view, they behave almost the same, they both can have argument labels, default values, etc.

Is there any real difference between the two, except that `subscript` uses square brackets `instance[index]` but `callAsFunction` uses parentheses `instance(index)`?

BTW, we know that `subscript` can have a setter, how about `callAsFunction`? Can it have a setter too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we know that subscript can have a setter, how about callAsFunction? Can it have a setter too?

It can't, because `callAsFunction` is just a regular *method* declared in your class/struct. Being able to call it without its name is just syntactic sugar achieved with compiler magic.

And that's pretty much the only practical difference between subscripts and `callAsFunction`.

But IMO the more important difference between them is not functionality-wise, but style-wise. Subscripts and function calls express different semantics. Subscripts express a "access/set something" semantic, and function call are more like "*do* something".

This idea is supported by Apple's [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/):

> Describe what a function or method *does* and what it *returns*

> Describe what a subscript *accesses*

Clearly, functions are supposed to *do* stuff, and subscripts are used to *access* stuff.

Let's use the example from [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/212/whats-new-in-swift-5-2):

```
struct Dice {
    var lowerBound: Int
    var upperBound: Int

    func callAsFunction() -> Int {
        (lowerBound...upperBound).randomElement()!
    }
}

let d6 = Dice(lowerBound: 1, upperBound: 6)
let roll1 = d6()
print(roll1)
```

Imagine how this would look if it were written with a subscript:

```
subscript() -> Int {
    (lowerBound...upperBound).randomElement()!
}

let roll1 = d6[]
```

It *works*, but `d6[]` just doesn't express the meaning of "roll the dice" as much as `d6()` does. It feels like I am accessing something in `d6`.

On the contrary, imagine dictionary accesses were instead like function calls:

```
let studentScores = ["Tom": 100, "Jack": 80, "Harry", 70]
let tomsScore = studentScores("Tom")
```

It feels like I am doing an action called `studentScores`. It would have been better if I renamed the dictionary to `studentScoresFor`, but that's a weird name for a dictionary...

Answer (score 1):

Subscripts can be set to read-write or read-only via the getter and setter methods. A callAsFunction() is a method that allows you to have parameters to perform some steps or functions.

#### Subscripts

Taking a look at the swift documentation on subscript we have
something like this.

> Source:
> https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Subscripts.html

```
subscript(index: Int) -> Int {
    get {
        // Return an appropriate subscript value here.
    }
    set(newValue) {
        // Perform a suitable setting action here.
    }
}
```

#### callAsFunction()

Calling a `callAsFunction()` does NOT have getters and setters. You might have something like this that returns a computed value.

> Source: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/212/whats-new-in-swift-5-2

```
struct StepCounter {
    var steps = 0

    mutating func callAsFunction(count: Int) -> Bool {
        steps += count
        print(steps)
        return steps > 10_000
    }
}

var steps = StepCounter()
let targetReached = steps(count: 10)
```